# CRC algorithm implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, crc, crc16

I'm implementing an CRC16 algorithm in C which is:

`init = 0x0000
as long as the data stream goes on
  if the first bit of data is not equal to the first bit of initial value
    init = leftshift init once and xor it with the polynomial
  otherwise
    leftshift init
go to the next data bit
init =  CRC Checksum`

Now the problem is... If I change the init value after the first comparison it's gonna always be equal to the data stream.

For example: If I get the initial value to be

`1011 0000 1011 0101`

and the data stream

`0011 0110 1000 0101`

after first iteration.

They are going to always be equal, since the `0's` at the beginning do not matter, and can be ignored.

And after the next iteration they are going to be:

`011 0000 1011 0101`

and data stream respectively

`011 0110 1000 0101`

but again the `0's` can be ignored and we get equality.

I'm really confused.

Here's my C code:

```
#define POLY 0x8005

int crc = 0x0000;   // Initial value
char data[1024];
int *dp = data;
int fd, nread;

fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
nread = read(fd, data, sizeof(data));
int *end = dp + nread;



while(data < end)
{
    crc = crc & 1 && data & 1 ? crc << 1 : (crc << 1) ^ POLY;
    data++;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the precedence when mixing `&` with `&&` in the same expression?

Comment: `crc & 1 && data & 1 ` is wrong. It should be `crc & 1 == data & 1` according to  "if the first bit of data is not equal to the first bit of initial value". If you really want to do it with logical operators, it should be `xor (not)`

Comment: This won't even compile. `data` is an array but you're doing things like `data & 1` and `data++`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. your suggestion would compile as `crc & (1 == data) & 1`

Comment: @WeatherVane Right. should always consult [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Was under the impression bitwise operators are in the same group as arithmetical ones...

Comment: Shifting `1011 0000 1011 0101` left by 1 would result in `0110 0001 0110 1010`, not `011 0000 1011 0101`.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues:

1. You're operating on the least significant bit but should be working on the most significant bit. This may be what's causing your confusion regarding bits staying the same, since you're looking at the wrong end of the values.
2. `crc & 1 && data & 1` checks that the bits are equal to 1 instead of checking that they are equal to each other.
3. You seem to be confused on whether `data` is an array (as declared), an integer (as used in `data & 1`), or a pointer (as used in `data++`).
4. If you change `data` to a pointer and increment it by 1 at each step, that would mean that you are only processing one bit from each input byte. You need an inner loop to process all 8 bits.

Comment: I don't quite get it how can I switch to operate on msb. Should I have a look on the leftmost bit or the rightmost one?